# Get a plane's center X, Y, Z, Cartesian coordinates

Tags: math, mathematical-optimization

I need to get a plane's center X, Y, Z, Cartesian coordinates. I have the plane's normal and its center point distance to origin.

I can place a point(s) anywhere and get the distance from it. I suppose that some kind of triangulation COULD be in order. Like placing three (or however many you need) points in some fashion to get a single point.

Answer (score 1):

If your plane is given in the following form:

```
dot(x, n) = d
```

, then it's quite easy to get an `x` that lies on the plane. Assuming that `n` is a unit vector, then `dot(n, n) = 1`. So, `dot(d * n, n) = d`. So one point on the plane is `d * n`.